# Clean up the tweets for sentiment analysis

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I used the following code to clean the corpus of the Username in the Tweet. But some names are in the word cloud. Why are they wrong?

```r
removeUsername <- function(x) gsub('@[^[:space:]]*', '', x)

removeURL <- function(x) gsub("http[:alnum:]*","",x) 
removeNumPunct<- function(x) gsub("[^[:alpha:][:space:]]*","",x) 
removeUsername <- function(x) gsub('@[^[:space:]]*', '', x) 
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus,PlainTextDocument) 
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus,content_transformer(removeURL)) 
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus,content_transformer(tolower))
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus,stripWhitespace) 
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus,content_transformer(removeNumPunct)) 
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus,content_transformer(removeNumbers))
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus, content_transformer(removeUsername))

Stopwords <- readLines("/Users/Stopwords.txt") 
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus, function(x) removeWords(x, Stopwords ))
```

Comment: This means, that your filtering is incorrect. Unfortunately, we can not help you since you did not provide an example input and example output. Both cover, idially, the variance of your problem.

Comment: how can i show an example I see inn the wordcloud that there were names.

Comment: Just provide a few example twitter handles your code doesn't seem to remove. Preferably in the message where they don't seem to dissappear as there might be something in the message that prevents the removal. Read this on how to create a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: After Clean. the tweets:"nulleberg  staat meldete    rekordsteuereinnahmen  bleibt  geld  dt steuerzahlers wi stcozwhqufy"

Comment: Before Clean: "@nulleberg Der Staat meldete doch über Jahre #Rekordsteuereinnahmen.\r\nDa bleibt das Geld des d…

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the order in which you execute your code. You first remove punctuation, and then you want to remove twitter handles. Which will not be found as removing the punctuation already removed the @. Same goes from stripping the whitespace, this is a step you should do at the end.

The following order should take care of the twitter handles and whitespace.

```
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus, PlainTextDocument) 
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus, content_transformer(removeUsername))
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus, content_transformer(removeURL)) 
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus, content_transformer(removeNumPunct)) 
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus, content_transformer(removeNumbers))
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus, stripWhitespace)
```

Also tm already contains functions fro removing puntuation and numbers, which can be used without `content_transformer`, like in the example below.

```
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus, removePunctuation)
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus, removeNumbers)
```

You could check the package quanteda. It has a lot of these twitter functions already included as flags in the `tokens` function.

Comment: @KenAS, cleaning is indeed 1 step. But I gave you just some advice. You need to use what works for you in a reproducible setting. I prefer quanteda over tm, but that is my preference. Others like tidytext, or qdap. Read the vignettes of all of them, try them out and stick to the one that works for you.